Understanding the calculation in the parametricplot command
I would like a little help to understand how the \parametricplot command works: I have a file which allows me to calculate the time derivative of the volume poured and I would like to understand it in order to be able to calculate the second derivative.
The command found in my file:
\parametricplot[style=\psk@Dosage@dpHstyle,plotpoints=400,yunit=\psk@Dosage@dpHunit]{pHmin}{pHmax}{%
t calc
/V1 V def
  %
t dt add calc
/V2 V def
V1 dt V2 V1 sub div
  }%

FYI, this command can be found in the pst-dosage package document: https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pc/pst-dosage/
Thanks

It makes no sense to use only a part of a macro to understand what happens.
You also need the definitions of /calc and /V to understand. However, the variable is t in the interval [pHmin, pHmax], with 400 steps. t is modified by  calc.  /V1  saves the current value of V (defined by calc) and then t gets the next value by adding dt (internally defined) and again modified by calc (and a new V). At the end we have the x-y values V1 and dt/(V2-V1).
The latest version is here: http://pstricks.blogspot.com/2023/11/courbes-de-dosage-ph-metrique-acide-base.html
